# How to check if a key, value pair exists in a dictionary in a collection in MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

So I wrote this code in python that is supposed to find if a particular key, value pair exists in a dictionary within a collection in MongoDB using PyMongo.

Here's the function -

```py
def check_for_item(user, item):
    item = db.collection.find({
        "uid": user.id,
        f"inv.{item}": {
            "$in": [
            1,
            10000
            ]
        }
    })
    return bool(item)
```

Now it doesn't work because even if there's an object that IS NOT THERE in the dictionary, it returns True for some reason, and I have no idea why this is happening.

This is how my collection looks:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/894468562578735174/894571908648018000/unknown.png

My collection as a dictionary:
`{'_id': ObjectId('6159a87c6f95d5b44277fd3d'), 'uid': 718712985371148309, 'wallet': 500, 'bank': 1000, 'bankl': 1500, 'job': 'None', 'salary': 0, 'inv': {'lock': 1}}`

Over here ^^^, as you can see there is a post called "inv" and under it is a key-value pair called "lock: 1"

So how do I get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its looks like inv is an object(not an array) with one field lock, maybe [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ProVvVY5AwQ) ? its what you need?

Comment: But what if the number of lock in the inv is more than 1?

Comment: lock is an array?

Comment: It looks like this:

Inv: {"lock": 1}